# ¿Metaetiqueta, Meta etiqueta o meta-etiqueta?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico

La tercera casi seguro que no. Pero, ¿y la primera y la segunda? ¿Cuál es la correcta?

Por un lado, Google usa "metaetiqueta" en sus páginas de ayuda. [Ejemplo](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=es):

> **Metaetiquetas** que Google entiende

Por otro lado, en la [Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metatag), aparece "meta etiqueta" (separado):

> Estas **meta etiquetas** también se usan para especificar cierta información técnica...

¿Cuál sería la correcta y por qué?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bajo la nueva ortografía, todos los prefijos se escriben soldados (sin espacio) a la palabra base excepto en dos casos:

- Intercálase un guión entre el prefijo y la base si esa empieza con mayúscula.
- Sepárase con un espacio el prefijo de la base si esa es pluriverbal (dos o más palabras).

Como *etiqueta* ni empieza con mayúscula, ni es pluriverbal, la forma correcta es **metaetiqueta**.

Comment: Y si estuviera a principio de frase (detrás de punto), sería Meta-etiqueta ?

Comment: Sería *Metaetiqueta*.  Aquí «empieza con mayúscula» se refiere a una palabra que obligatoriamente tiene mayúscula (siglas, nombres propios, etc).